# how to store video recorded in a specific path

Tags: android, video, path, recording

I'm trying to record video using the default camera app. Here is the intent passed to the camera app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and this below is the `onResultActivity()`

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String path=data.getData().getPath();
    File file=new File(path);
    boolean exists=file.exists();
    long idMedia = mApp.saveMedia(mFilePath, Type.VIDEO).getId();
}
```

So, the path returned is something like "/external/video/media/15"

First question is: where is the /external directory? I cannot find it via adb shell neither using a file explorer on the device.

Second question: the boolean exists is false. Why?

Third (and most important) question: how can I move the video recorded in a specific directory on sdcard?

I tried passing the uri file using

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
```

but the camera app stuck when I press the record button and still the data Intent of `onResultActivity()` point to the "/external/...." directory.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> "/external/video/media/15"

is not absolute path but its URI,
You have to find absolute path using contentproviders.
To store it in specific path you should use

> .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,path)

in intent while calling camera

Comment: Ok thanks. So I have to pass the string path instead of the uri to `.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,path)` right? Because the official documentation says different [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-video). Btw, putting the path for the camera app does not create the file. I'm passing a directory in the sdcard.